# Being + P.P construct as progressive form of -ed participle or passive form

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles, participles, present-participles

Regarding **Being + P.P** construct:

In [*The Grammar Book*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1111351864) it is described as **Progressive**:
[image]

but the same construct in [*Cambridge Grammar of English*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521581664) is described as **Passive**:

[image]

Which one is correct?

Comment: 'Being worn out' with the adjectival usage is, like 'being exhausted',  'being tired', and 'being sleepy', not a passive construction. 'Being broken' _may_ be considered passive: 'Being broken by the ball, the glass was obviously missold as 'unbreakable',  but may be similar in nature to 'being sleepy': 'Being broken, the slide is of no use'.

Comment: Interesting question - I agree with Edwin that 'Being worn out' could be seen as either adjectival or adverbial, but that both relate to a verb in the active voice and that 'Being consulted' relates to a verb in the passive voice - unless I'm mistaken, your examples are examples of different uses of 'Being + PP'.

Comment: To be clear, by "P.P" you mean "past participle"?

Comment: Again, this isn't a question about grammar; everyone agrees about grammaticality. It's about what to call constructions and how to define them. And what to call the various parts of the constructions and how to define **them**. D.C. al Fine.

Comment: @MJ713 Yes, P.P is past participle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Being worn out** from all the work, John decided to relax for the evening.

While this sentence is grammatical, I disagree with *The Grammar Book*'s interpretation. "Worn out" is not a participle in this sentence; rather, it is simply an adjective ([Source 1](https://www.lexico.com/definition/worn_out), [Source 2](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/worn-out)). This being the case, the phrase "being worn out" is a *participial phrase* ([Source 1](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/sentences/participial-phrases.html), [Source 2](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-phrase-1691588), [Source 3](https://englishsentences.com/participial-phrase/)). Participial phrases act as adjectives. In this case, the phrase is describing the subject of the sentence, John. "Being" is the present participle of "to be", not a helper to another verb, and "worn out" is the subject complement. Who is worn out? John is worn out.

I agree with *The Grammar Book* in one respect: the use of "being" *does* emphasize that John's "worn-out-ness" is the "reason or cause for the result expressed in the main clause", i.e. deciding to relax.

---

> **Being consulted** on the matter would have been nice too.

This is also a grammatical sentence, and it is undoubtedly an example of a passive voice construction. The implied subject of the sentence, "I", would be the object of the verb in an active construction.

Note that the use of "being" here is a specific case of a general principle. We create passive-voice constructions *in general* by pairing the past participle with *various* tenses of the verb "to be" ([Source 1](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/passive-voice/), [Source 2](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/passive.html)).

*Active Voice:*

> They **consult** me on the matter.
>
> I **consulted** Terry last week.
>
> **Consulting** me would have been nice.

*Passive Voice:*

> I **am consulted** by them on the matter.
>
> Terry **was consulted** by me last week.
>
> **Being consulted** would have been nice.

---

In short, the first example is not a case of "'being' + [past participle]" at all, and the second example is a specific case of "[form of *to be*] + [past participle]".